# Navigation Drawer in Multiple Activities in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer in Xamarin using Visual Studio 2017. 
I created the navigation drawer after some research in google. But when I try to open activities from the menu, navigation drawer disappears.

I want to have my navigation drawer in all my activities, without repeating it in all activities.

Link to my project: https://github.com/Chindara/XamarinAndroidNavigationDrawer

Updated link: https://github.com/Chindara/XamarinAndroid-NavigationDrawer

Comment: You mean when you open an Activity, the navigation drawer still 
displayed on the Activity?

Comment: @YorkShen No. When I open an activity from the navigation drawer, activity will be opened without the navigation drawer.

Comment: Sorry,  I don't really get the meaning of this sentence, " navigation drawer in all my activities, without repeating it in all activities", can you explain it ?

Comment: @YorkShen - When I run the application navigation drawer is there. Then I click on a menu item to open another page. But then navigation drawer is missing.
I want navigation drawer to be in all my activities. I don't want to repeat the menu coding in every activity. 
Like putting the menu on a master page of an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click a menu item, you should navigate to a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=en-us) instead of an `Activity`, `Framework` can also display the user interface. If you doing this, when you select a `Fragment`, the `navigation drawer` will always in your `Activitiy`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9SPu.gif). Here is the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/) about how to use `Fragment` in `Xamarin`.

When you select your menu item :

```
navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);

            FragmentTransaction ft = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            if (e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.nav_MGrade)
            {
                MGradeFragment mg = new MGradeFragment();
                // The fragment will have the ID of Resource.Id.fragment_container.
                ft.Replace(Resource.Id.ll, mg);
            }
            else if(e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.home)
            {
                //...
            }
            //...

            // Commit the transaction.
            ft.Commit();
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };
```

`MGradeFragment.class`, did the same thing as your `MGradeActivity`:

```
public class MGradeFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        View view = LayoutInflater.From(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MGradesView, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The `MGradeFragment` will replace the `LinearLayout` in your Main.axml :

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        >
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And in your `toolbar.axml`, modify your code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ....
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">//Change match_parent to wrap_content
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @york-shen. Very helpful detailed answer. I have updated my GitHub project with the solution.